# Windows Universal App break all timers on suspended event

Tags: c#, windows, push-notification, windows-phone, win-universal-app

In my application i use multiple timers for support specific business logic. Like this:

`ScheduleRepeatTimerAction(() =>
{
   if(_condition)
      ShowSystemToast();
}, 1000);`

If specified condition becoming true, i must show SystemToast(LocalPushNotification) for user.

General problem in app suspended event.
After application move to suspended state (app move to background), app logic-timers has stopped and Toast never showed while app not resumed.

How to wake up my timers with application logic in suspended state?

Answer (score 0):

That is what you should expect from the [application lifecycle management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974425(v=vs.120).aspx).

If it gets suspended, then the application will not run and use system resources anymore.

Instead, try doing the same but with [background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task). These will allow your application to run code even if it is not being executed.

Keep in mind that a [background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/index) is not guaranteed to be executed as there are restrictions such as CPU clock time usage and user permissions.